# Is it more practical to define an IDT at assemble time, or build it in memory programmatically from a bootloader/kernel?

Tags: assembly, kernel, bootloader

It seems to me there is alot of work to be done when writing yourself a complete IDT. Writing all the handlers, ect. Even with things like macro's and "times" directives to help you. If an IDT
consists of 256 qwords (more or less) that hold information about ir handlers to call, flags, segment selector, ect. Would it not be easier just to get yourself into pmode, pick yourself a memory location and programmatically create everything you need there? If you start at address 0x7bfff, and build all 256 entries up to 0x7ffff, making sure to give them the address of a common handler to call more specific handlers from, flags, selector, ect. And then you know your base and limit to. Then just fill in the idt pointer, load it, and prey that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practicality is always a *subjective* perception. As such, your question cannot be completely answered. Nonetheless we can look at some arguments for and against building the interrupt descriptor table (IDT) at run time:

Basically, your question boils down to whether to generate constant data (the IDT) at run or compile time. Assuming that the same amount of data will be generated, no matter when, we have some usual arguments:

- **program size**: If you include the fully generated data, then the size of your program (in this case the kernel) will increase, leading to potentially longer initial load times. Of course this is only the case if the data could be generate by code whose size is negligible compared to the size of the data.
- **execution time**: Generating data at run time involves "doing stuff", thus increasing the execution time. Depending on how long it takes to generate the data, and how often it needs to be generated, this is either a serious issue or negligible.

In the context of a kernel, I can think of the following circumstances that would require pondering between the two options:

- Limited read only memory (ROM) for the kernel (along with other code) to be placed in. In this case, generating the IDT at run time is favorable to reduce the static memory footprint. This won't happen to you unless in an embedded setting with (very) limited memory available.
- Critical boot times. If in some hard real time setting, and your system shuts down (due to an update, failure, ...), then you want it to be up again as quickly as possible. Generating the IDT at run time could increase the boot time just a bit too much. On the other hand, loading static data also takes time. IMHO it's very unlikely that you need to consider this.

For all other situations, there won't be much of a difference in terms of such "measurable" metrics. Consider though that there are some trade offs concerning debugging and run time generated data; when using a static IDT you can validate it before even running the kernel.

That's where another aspect of practicability comes in:

> [..] Writing all the handlers, ect. Even with things like macro's and "times" directives to help you. [..]

This is, of course, extremely depending on how you would actually write a static IDT. Basically, nobody stops you from writing a (user) program to emit a correct IDT to be linked into your kernel, utilizing the same code that you would put into the kernel (or even simpler code than that). So having to "write all the handlers" is a deficit of your tools, and as such not directly related to whether generating them at run time or not.

In a [hobbyist kernel I wrote long ago](http://repo.or.cz/w/kernel.git) I created handlers (code) "by hand" (I would do this differently now ^^) and the actual IDT (data) during run time:

```
// src/idt/idt.c
void IDT_SetGate (UINT8 num, UINT base, UINT16 sel, UINT8 flags)
{
  UINT *tmp;    
  tmp = IDT;
  tmp += num * 2;   
  *tmp = (base & 0xFFFF);
  *tmp |= (sel & 0xFFFF) << 16;
  tmp++;
  *tmp = (flags & 0xFF) << 8;
  *tmp |= (base & 0xFFFF0000);
}

// src/int/isr.c
void ISR_Setup (void)
{
  IDT_SetGate(0, (unsigned)_isr0, 0x08, 0x8E);
  IDT_SetGate(1, (unsigned)_isr1, 0x08, 0x8E);
  // ... a lot more, an array would've been the better choice :D
}
```

I then had minimal handlers `_isr0`, `_isr1`, ... which called a common handler **after saving the interrupt number and dealing with error codes**. Which is the main argument against:

> [..] making sure to give them the address of a common handler to call more specific handlers from [..]

At least on x86 you need distinct handlers for the different interrupts, because otherwise you cannot tell which interrupt fired. To truly generate even the handlers at run time you would need some sort of specialized assembler, which aids you in code generation at run time. I wouldn't call that "practical" anymore.